# Find the max value of a function at a given interval

Tags: optimization, roots, maximum-principle

Trying to determine local max for a function at interval $[-4, 6]$.  $$f(x)= x^3 -3x^2-24x + 7$$

Is the proper next step to take the derivative of $f(x)$ and find the roots, set roots = to zero?

Comment: What happened when you did that?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Take the derivative, find the zeros, test those points. You should get $x = -2, 4$ (a Min and a Max).
- Plot the function and verify.

Comment: Simple as that! +1

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)=3x^2-6x-24$. Now, you get the maximum point when $f'(x)=0$. That is when $x=-2$ or $x=4$.

Now, in order to know if it is a minimum or maximum, notice that your function is positive from [$-2,0$] and negative from [$0,6$]. Therefore, $x=-2$ is the maximum you are looking for ($x=4$ is a minimum.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, find $f'(x) =0, x \in [-4,6]$, then test the zeros and the endpoints of your interval.